# How to get Flycheck (using clang_complete) to recognize the OpenGL framework on Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, emacs, clang, flycheck

I'm trying to get Flycheck to correctly see where OpenGL is on my Mac, but it can't seem to find it. I've tried adding the following lines to my `.clang_complete` file, but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the error `OpenGL/gl.h could not be found`:

```
-framework OpenGL
-I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers
```

This doesn't happen during compilation, it's just messing up static analysis and compilation by Irony. The directory I listed has `gl.h` and `glu.h` in it directly, which is probably why it didn't help to add, but I can't figure out how to get Irony to see the files correctly.

Edit: Using Flycheck for syntax checking, not Irony

Edit: macOS X Framework directory:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
    OpenGL.framework/
        Headers/
        Modules/
        OpenGL.tbd/
        Versions/
```

Comment: I just checked on my linux box and it works fine - using `c/c++-clang` checker with zero configuration, using gl.h and glut.h, so I assume you''re correct it is a macOS issue.  I also don't use the `-framework` argument

Comment: Yeah, but you have to use frameworks on OS X. That's how OpenGL is installed. I'll add an edit to show the framework directory in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one seems to have an answer on this, I'll post my workaround. By symlinking `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers` to `/usr/local/include/OpenGL`, you can give the checker the file path it wants, fixing the issue. Not the best solution, but a decent workaround nonetheless.